# Pytorch: Weighting in BCEWithLogitsLoss, but with 'weight' instead of 'pos_weight'

Tags: pytorch

I'm looking how to do class weighting using BCEWithLogitsLoss.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html

The example on how to use `pos_weight` seems clear to me. If there are 3x more negative samples than positive samples, then you can set pos_weight=3

Does the `weight` parameter do the same thing?

Say that I set it `weight=torch.tensor([1, 3])`. Is that the same thing as `pos_weight=3`

Also, is `weight` normalized? Is `weight=torch.tensor([1, 3])` the same as `weight=torch.tensor([3, 9])`, or are they different in how they affect the magnitude of the loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different things. `pos_weight` is size n_classes. `weight` is size `batch_size`. In the formula in the page you linked, `weight` refers to the `w_n` variable, whereas `pos_weight` refers to the `p_c` variable.